# get fragment values in url

Tags: go, httphandler

sample code

```html
func main() {
 fmt.Print("starting box web server...")
 http.HandleFunc("/", landing)
 http.HandleFunc("/handle", handler)
 http.ListenAndServe(connector_port, nil)
}
func landing(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
 fmt.Println("redirecting to login for authentication...")
 http.Redirect(w, r, "http://*****urlfortoken", http.StatusFound)
}
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
 bodyresnew_folder, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
 fmt.Println("response Body:", string(bodyresnew_folder))
 fmt.Println("1", r.GetBody)
 fmt.Println("2", r.URL.String())
 fmt.Println("3", r.URL.Fragment)
 fmt.Println("4", r.URL.Query().Get("access_token"))
 fmt.Println("inside handle function,", r.Form.Get("access_token"))
 fmt.Println("finished processing all files please close this server manually")
}
```

I tried the code above to get fragment from an URL but was unsuccessful.

Example URL used is: `http://localhost:8080/handle#access_token=*1234$111&token_type=bearer&expires_in=3600&scope=onedrive.readwrite&user_id=hashed`

Now, for such URL, I want to get the value of fragment `access_token` in the `handler` function which is basically an http handler.

Comment: Fragments are not sent to the server. So you cannot "get" them: An incoming request does not contain the fragment.

Comment: @Volker ohh thanks for the information

Answer (score 3):

As commenters pointed already, fragment is not part of your request. Fragment can be rather a subset of your HTML markup, identified by some ID - that'd be a thing returned by the server.

I am wondering why wouldn't you use GET parameters?

Then your URL could be

```
http://localhost:8080/handle?access_token=*1234$111&token_type=bearer&expires_in=3600&scope=onedrive.readwrite&user_id=hashed
```

that is, with `?` instead of `#` after the `/handle`

Then you will see your `access_token` GET parameter properly:

```
inside handle function, 
1 <nil>
2 /handle?access_token=*1234$111&token_type=bearer&expires_in=3600&scope=onedrive.readwrite&user_id=hashed
3 
4 *1234$111
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i cannot command server to send URL with parameter instead of fragments

Comment: You mean the client. Client sends this

Comment: So I can guess that for some reason you want to encode your parameters as a fragment id. But it has minimal chances to work. Fragment identifier has specific syntax allowed, for example.

I believe now it's the time to ask question - why such design? What are your limitations which prevent you from using a more common and straightforward way?

Comment: its the way to get access token for microsoft onedrive, in which we will get accesstoken in fragment